# Вставка файла html в html файл на сервере (include)?

Tags: html, html5, asp.net, include

В ASP есть команда, которая вставляет один файл html в другой.

```
<!--#include virtual="blocks/form1.aspx" -->
```

И это происходит на стороне сервера. 
А есть ли в стандарте html5, какие нибудь указания для веб сервера вставлять один файл в другой? Или это только в настройках каждого веб сервера делается?

Comment: Такие директивы используются не в HTML5, а в стандарте [SSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSI_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Comment: @mymedia
А если веб сервер не IIS и не apache? 
Такой способ вставки самый правильный и рекомендуемый?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать посредством тегов `<frame>` и `<iframe>`
Проще и удобнее(на мой взгляд) - использовать PHP, для этого нужно будет изменить тип файла на .php
Пример такого встраивания:

```
<?php 
require_once 'page1.html';//так же можно с помощью require, include, include_once
//И тут может быть остальной текст


?>
```

Comment: Нет, я спрашивал про "склейку" файлов на стороне сервера, без привязки к языку или веб серверу.